# endpoints (bug?) behavior in xts

Tags: r, xts

If I try to get `endpoints` for every year, for example, and do the following:

```
xts.data <- xts(1:10000, order.by=seq(from=as.Date("1970-01-01"), by=1, len=10000))
z <- endpoints(xts.data, on="months", k=12)
```

The return value for this is:

```
> z
[1]     0 10000
```

Same with numbers higher than 12. Why would `xts` simply not return indices of every year or 13th month starting from the beginning.  Is it limited by the number of periods in a year? That is if i did:

```
 z <- endpoints(xts.data, on="weeks", k=54)
```

This seems to work fine.

Comment: What about just doing `endpoints(xts.data, on="years")`?

Comment: yes that works but what if i'm trying to do this dynamically without having to check if we have reached the 12 month point. also i would like to know if this is a bug or it is part of the functionality

Comment: If you look at the code, it tries to match `k` to `posixltindex$mon` (0 from 11). The fact it does not work with `k >= 12` or higher is a consequence of that implementation; I wouldn't call it a bug. Now whether it should warn, die or not when `k >= 12` is debatable.

Comment: indeed. this does not seem like the ideal behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This looks like something of an implementation gotcha.  I'll add a fix to R-forge once I can test the version I am working on more completely.

**UPDATED** *twice*

There is now a patch on this in rev 742 on R-forge.  It isn't likely final, but ideally this is the direction.

```
> head(xts.data[z])
       [,1]
1970-12-31  365
1971-12-31  730
1972-12-31 1096
1973-12-31 1461
1974-12-31 1826
1975-12-31 2191

> head(xts.data[endpoints(xts.data, on="months", k=1)])
           [,1]
1970-01-31   31
1970-02-28   59
1970-03-31   90
1970-04-30  120
1970-05-31  151
1970-06-30  181
> head(xts.data[endpoints(xts.data, on="months", k=2)])
           [,1]
1970-02-28   59
1970-04-30  120
1970-06-30  181
1970-08-31  243
1970-10-31  304
1970-12-31  365
> head(xts.data[endpoints(xts.data, on="months", k=3)])
           [,1]
1970-03-31   90
1970-06-30  181
1970-09-30  273
1970-12-31  365
1971-03-31  455
1971-06-30  546
> head(xts.data[endpoints(xts.data, on="months", k=4)])
           [,1]
1970-04-30  120
1970-08-31  243
1970-12-31  365
1971-04-30  485
1971-08-31  608
1971-12-31  730
> head(xts.data[endpoints(xts.data, on="months", k=6)])
           [,1]
1970-06-30  181
1970-12-31  365
1971-06-30  546
1971-12-31  730
1972-06-30  912
1972-12-31 1096
> head(xts.data[endpoints(xts.data, on="months", k=7)])
           [,1]
1970-07-31  212
1971-02-28  424
1971-09-30  638
1972-04-30  851
1972-11-30 1065
1973-06-30 1277
```

Comment: should i leave this open so people run across and hopefully test the patch?

Comment: On S.O.?  I don't venture around here often enough to be useful in that regard.  I left it open on xts-bugs until I am sure it is solved.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that this is a bug, or at least a limitation that needs to be documented: the `k` for "months" only works for k=1,2,3,4 and 6.

Finding workarounds, my first idea was:

```
 library(xts)
 x <- xts(1:10000, order.by=seq(from=as.Date("1970-01-01"), by=1, len=10000))
 index(x)[endpoints(x, on="months", k=6)[c(T,F)]]
```

giving:

```
 "1970-12-31" "1971-12-31" "1972-12-31"... "1995-12-31" "1996-12-31"
```

But it breaks when I use a different set of data:

```
x <- xts(1:10000, order.by=seq(from=as.Date("1970-07-01"), by=1, len=10000))
```

which gives:

```
"1971-06-30" "1972-06-30" "1973-06-30" ...
```

A stable answer is:

```
dates <- index(x)[endpoints(x, on="months", k=6)]
dates[ as.POSIXlt(dates)$mon==11 ]
```

(In English: *get the last day of each half-year, and only keep the ones in December.*)

An alternative is to just use `endpoints(x, on="years")`, and then remove the last date if you don't like it.

I'm guessing you want "last trading day" or "last sample day" of the year, so it won't actually be Dec 31st in each year. But if you did want a specific date each year:

```
index(x)[.indexmon(x)==11 & .indexmday(x)==31]
```

Comment: @GSee Using k=7 doesn't give you dates every 7 months apart; instead it gives you last day of July, and last day of December. k=11 gives you last day of November and last day of December for each year. k=5 gives last day of May, October and December. This is very different behaviour to how k works with "weeks" or "days" or "years".

Comment: i submitted a bug report - REALLY surprising this has not come up before.. seems like a pretty basic issue unless we are all missing something

Comment: @DarrenCook: i haven't accepted the answer yet just in case one of the developers sees this and can comment